# Systems that Access AD Attributes

Tags: active-directory, attributes

I have been assigned a task to export the AD Attributes than find out what systems are using these attributes. I have not had much luck in scripting or a tool that can provide just that. Is this feasible and if so how? I have already exported attributes. Just need to find what systems are using them.

Comment: Was "using them" defined for you? This sounds like an impossible task.

Comment: No it was not defined. Unfortunately, my manager wants to know all the applications that access user/computer attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with any reasonable accuracy, especially if "using" isn't defined for you.

The event logs on the domain controllers will tell you where login events are coming from, but only by IP. That doesn't tell you which application is authenticating. You would have to do monitoring on that computer and see which application is making the connection. But then the logs would be cluttered with connections made by Windows itself, or Exchange (if you use Exchange for email). It it would be very difficult to identify what is coming from an 3rd-party application rather than Windows itself.

Also, applications can request more information than they need. It's very easy when programming with LDAP to request every attribute for an object, even if you only intend to use one. For example, take this C# code:

```cs
var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://example.com");
Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["name"].Value);
```

That only "uses" the `name` attribute. But because of the way LDAP works, it actually requests *every* non-constructed attribute that has a value. (there is a way to specifically ask for only one attribute, but you have to know that and use that)

So even if you could find logs saying that "this IP requested all of these attributes", and then figure out which application made that request, that doesn't mean it "used" all of those attributes.